# Show a form filed by clicking a link on different results of a mysql select query while loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this code:

***CSS file:***

```
#answerform {
    display: none;
}
```

***PHP file:***

```
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

<?php   
    $sql="SELECT comment FROM comments 
ORDER BY comments.id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error ( mysql_error ( )); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div>";
  echo $row['comment'];
  echo "</br>";

  // Answer to comment
    echo "<a id=hrefanswer href='#'> Answer </a>";

    // Answer form
    echo "<div id=answerform>";
    echo "<input type='text' value='' name='answer' id='answer'/>";
    echo "</div>";


  echo "</div>";
  }
  ?>

<script>

       $('#hrefanswer').click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
          $('#answerform').show();
          });  

</script>
```

I use the code to display some comments, using mysql select query, and in each comment have a link (Answer). When clicking on the link I want to hide the link and at the same time show a form filed. The problem is that this happens only to the last comment, and not in every comment of the select mysql query. Why?

Comment: IDs on HTML elements have to be unique - if you're dynamically creating them using a loop, you need some kind of incrementing counter to ensure that the IDs you're attaching to those elements are, in fact, unique (which they're not in your code). Or, better yet, do away with IDs and use classes instead, which can apply to more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are duplicating the Id of the `div` added in the loop - ids must be unique.

Change the `a` and `div` to use a class:

```
echo "<a class=hrefanswer href='#'> Answer </a>";
// more code
echo "<div class=answerform>";
```

Then amend your jQuery like this:

```
$('.hrefanswer').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().next(".answerform").show();
});
```

Also, your PHP file is missing a `</script>` at the top, and you should enclose every HTML attribute in quotes.